# How to create a "fake" tab in react navigation that does not navigate to a component, but only is seen as active

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Is it possible to have a tab with BottomTabNavigator that is a "fake" tab that just runs a "onPress" on the current tab that it's on and also marks it as "active"

I would have 3 tabs: Home, Chat, More.

Home is a WebView

When I click the "More" tab, i want to append to the url of the WebView and also mark the "More" tab active.

When I click "Home", I want to remove the appended url from the WebView, and mark the "Home" tab as active

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, just forget doing it with react navigation if you don't want to navigate, and use TouchableOpacity `onPress={() => this.setState({activeTab: 'home'})}`

Structure it like this.

1 Dashboard component that renders 3 different types of content depending on what this.state.activeTab is. This will always show all three tabs, but the active one can be highlighted.

3 child components that are the content you want to see depending on the active tab.

Should be pretty straightforward but leave a comment if something isn't clear and I'll try to help out.